# How to install FFMPEG on windows server..?

Tags: ffmpeg

Thanks in advance..

I would like to install ffmpeg on my windows server.

My php version is 5.2.3.

i followed and copied the avcodec.dll and
avformat.dll files to system32 folder.and i copied ffmpeg file into php5\ext folder.Then i added tha extension php_ffmpeg in ini file extension.

and also ffmpex.exe in c:/ffmpeg folder.

i give the full rights of that all files.

But ffmpeg still not working.

Anyone guide me which thing i missed.....

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I made an installer for ffmpeg here is a single line install command:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leo-Aqua/Windows-FFMPEG-installer/main/FFmpeg-insataller.bat -o %TEMP%/FFmpeg-insataller.bat -# && powershell Start-Process "%TEMP%\FFmpeg-insataller.bat" -Verb RunAs
```

Answer (score -2):

I did not use as an extension as my server was 64bit. If you like to use exec(), then you can use like following example:

```
$cmd = "c:/wamp/www/ffmpeg.exe -i c:/wamp/www/a.mpg -sameq -ar 22050 c:/wamp/www/b.mpg";

$test = exec($cmd);
```

Source: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: Explanation is more important than downvote if someone has not already pointed out the reason in comments for downvote.